# Create a new job in SQL Server 2005 with the use of code

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

How can you create a new job in SQL Server 2005 with the use of code? And not in SQL Server Management Studio.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a series of system stored procedures that you should use as detailed on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181153(SQL.90).aspx):

[sp_add_job](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182079(SQL.90).aspx)
[sp_add_jobstep](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187358(SQL.90).aspx)

Plus a couple more for settings up schedules.

Answer (score 2):

To see how it's done by example, you can make a job in Management Studio, then right-click / script the job out to a query window.